# Translating curl into Matlab/Webwrite

Tags: matlab, curl

I have the following curl command I need to sent to a web server using Matlab and webwrite using POST. My problem is that I always get a "Bad request" answer so my syntax must be wrong somehow. Does anybody have an idea how this curl command, sending the body could look like in Matlab using webwrite in a correct way ?

```
body=$(cat << EOF
{
  "order": {
    "units": "100",
    "instrument": "EUR_USD",
    "timeInForce": "FOK",
    "type": "MARKET",
    "positionFill": "DEFAULT"
  }
}
EOF
)

curl \
  -X POST \
  -H "Content-Type: application/json" \
  -H "Authorization: Bearer <AUTHENTICATION TOKEN>" \
  -d "$body" \
  "https://api-fxtrade.oanda.com/v3/accounts/<ACCOUNT>/orders"
```

Answer (score 1):

I have just asked a potentially similar question so this may not work first time. However I cannot test without knowing some login details so I can but hope this helps.

```
data_InputValues = struct ('units',100,'instrument','EUR_USD','timeInForce','FOK','type','MARKET','positionFill','DEFAULT');
MyBody = matlab.net.http.MessageBody(struct('order',data_InputValues));

MyHTTPOptions = matlab.net.http.HTTPOptions(); % use this to change the options if necessary (e.g. extend timeout)
Request = matlab.net.http.RequestMessage;
Request.Method = 'POST';
Request.Header = matlab.net.http.HeaderField('Content-Type','application/json','Authorization: Bearer',AUTHENTICATION TOKEN);
Request.Body = MyBody;
uri = matlab.net.URI('https://api-fxtrade.oanda.com/v3/accounts/<ACCOUNT>/orders');
[response a ~] = Request.send(uri,MyHTTPOptions);
```

The part I struggle with is generating the MyBody part (in your case this is parsing the order variable's sub-variables). If you get this to work I would be keen to know how! P.S. my question in case it helps: [Matlab RESTful PUT Command - net.http - nesting body values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50416587/matlab-restful-put-command-net-http-nesting-body-values)

Answer (score 1):

The correct format for the **body** is as follows:

```
body = struct('units',100,'instrument','EUR_USD','timeInForce','FOK',...
   'type','MARKET','positionFill','DEFAULT');
```

As for the HTTP **headers** that you require you can specify them with [weboptions](https://uk.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/weboptions.html) when using [webwrite](https://uk.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/webread.html).

The syntax for an additional header:

```
options = weboptions('KeyName','Name','KeyValue','Value')
```

Where *Name* and *Value* are the name of the header and its value respectively.
You must add the headers that you require in weboptions.

For the code you provided, the correct syntax would be as follows:

```
options = weboptions('MediaType','application/json',...
'KeyName','Authorization: Bearer','KeyValue','Token');
```

You can then perform the POST request at the URL of interest.

```
response = webwrite(url,body,options);
```